# How to make a console application receive an input of 100,000 integers

Tags: c, input, io, cmd

I have a simple C console application and I'm trying to test it with an input of 100,000. But the program only receives about 4,096 characters each time. This is a simple example of input:

```
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1    //Up to 100,000
```

It works if I manually write a number each time, but I want to just paste the input(100,000 space-separated numbers) into the console.

PS: Sorry for my English, it's not very good

EDIT: Yes, the platform I'm using is Windows cmd. And I have already tried "Properties>Options>Buffer Size".

Example of the code:

```
int a[100000],i;
for(i=0;i<100000;i++)
    scanf("%i",&a[i]);
```

Print screen of the test:
[image]

Comment: sounds like buffering. but you'll need to post some more context. Code for example I think

Comment: what platform is your console? Windows cmd? linux shell?

Comment: Are you trying to use something like `fread()` or `fgets()` or `fscanf()` to get the input? Is it important that it happen entirely within one `read()` OS-level call?

Comment: There's a problem with your read loop. Show us your code.

Comment: `int a[100000]` Can ensure that the stack?

Comment: Yes, it does. But the problem is not on the code, but when passing the input in a single line on cmd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard IO routines (such as `printf()` and `scanf()`) use [buffering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_buffer) to improve performance and provide some nice standardized routines (such as `fgets()` to read in a line at a time). Making function calls is usually significantly faster than making system calls; if you were to write an application using system calls to read one byte of data at a time it would run significantly slower than an application that reads 1024 bytes at a time or larger.

This is almost always a wonderful thing.

But it does mean that you need to write your applications carefully. You cannot simply issue a single `read()`-style function that will read all the data at once. (The amount of available data may be significantly greater than the amount of memory and swap space available on the machine, too, so even if you could, it would not be very reliable in all use cases.)

Applications that handle a stream of input tend to have a loop something like these:

```
int c;
while ((c = getc()) != EOF) {
    /* handle the character c */
}
```

or

```
char buffer[1024];
while (fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, F)) {
    /* handle buffer */
}
```

The first case is convenient because you never need to worry about input that's been broken across two or more "buffers" -- but the first case does mean `sscanf()` and similar tools can't help you parse numbers. The second case does allow you to use `sscanf()` when parsing, but you have to be prepared for an input to span across two buffers. This is easier to spot if the buffer is only eight bytes: `buffer[8]` and you wish to read in a 32-byte MD5sum or a `double` that requires more than eight characters to express: `1234567890`. The  first read will get the first eight bytes, the second read will get the next two bytes, and you'll have to construct your number.

Comment: It's a good alternative, but I only want to read the input with `scanf("%i",&temp)` 100,000 times

Comment: Hrm. When I try your little snippet of code on my Linux machine it runs to completion just fine. Perhaps `int a[100000]` is blowing the stack available to your program -- try `int *a = malloc(100000 * sizeof int);` to allocate the memory dynamically.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not explaining very well. The problem is not on my c code. It's when I try to write the input of the 100,000 numbers(1 1 1 1...) in the same line

Comment: So if all 100,000 numbers are separated by newlines your code works fine but if they are all on one line separated by spaces your code dies?

Comment: Yes, exactly. So it's inconvenient to write manually the 100,000 numbers whereas (if possible) I can just paste the whole input directly

Comment: When I tested your program on my Linux machine, I used `yes 1` to generate the inputs; it generates a never ending stream of `1` characters separated by newlines. To test the space-case, I used `yes 1 | tr '\n' ' ' | ./foo`. If those tools are easily available to you, they can make these sorts of tests way easier.

Comment: I'll try it. Could you edit your answer? The it would be easier to understand and I'll be abble to check your answer

Comment: I'm not sure what I'd edit it _to_ -- I was planning on re-writing the answer as necessary or deleting it outright depending upon what the eventual outcome turns out to be. I don't know what I would re-write it to include right now...

Answer (score 1):

You can create a file with the 100K integers, then pipe it to your app. For example:

```
cat myInput.txt | myApp
```

Or in Windows:

```
type myInput.txt | myApp
```

Comment: I tried this way, but cmd returned "The process tried to write to a nonexistent pipe". What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @egrunin Now it doesn't returns anything, neither error nor the program result